# Uniform gift to minors act stock sold by state under escheatment?

Tags: stocks, inheritance

My grandmother bought me a stock of Disney when I was born and now in graduate school I decided now would be a good idea to cash in on the stock. It was only one share but the stock has split 1:3 and then 1:4 since that time and could be worth a small decent sum at today's going rate for the stock. I checked my states (wisconsin) unclaimed property IRS website and saw I had two unclaimed properties from the same company the stock share was in. I requesting and received the two unclaimed property sums but am left wondering if those properties were the unclaimed dividends of the stock or the stock themselves sold by the state under escheatment acts. The brokerage company the stock was bought through was bought by Wells Fargo. I am curious because the difference in the current value of the stock I hold is $1200 but if it was sold by the state my claim for the unclaimed property was valued and $500. so basically I want to know if I might still own the stock or if it was sold. Thank you.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to find out how much dividends have been paid in the past 20 years.